# Row callback function, find a column by name, not by number

Tags: datatables

In my datatables table, I have a row callback function defined like this:

```
'rowCallback': function (row, data, index) {
    rowCallback(row, data, index);
},
```

The Javascript function that is called looks like this:

```
function rowCallback(row, data, index) {
    $(row).find('td:eq(0)').css('background', data.LaborTypeColorHexValue);
}
```

This works fine. However, I don't like finding a column by column number. I'd much rather search by column name in the event the column order gets switched around. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().names(), you can get the index by column name:

```
var index = table.columns().names().indexOf('Salary');
```

You can then pass that index to your jQuery selector.

Comment: how to get the 'table' variable in the rowCallback function?

Answer (score 0):

[Since](https://www.datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) datatables 1.10.0: You must use :name after column name.

```
var index = table.column('my_column_name:name')[0][0]
var index = table.columns('my_column_name:name')[0][0]
```

[Since](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().names()) datatables 2.0.0:

```
var index = table.columns().names().indexOf( 'my_column_name' );
```

Example v1.x.x:

```
table = $('#mytable').DataTable( {
    "columns": [
        { "data": "", "name": "my_column_name" }],
    //......... (name can be also set in columnDefs section.

    "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
         var index = table.columns('my_column_name:name')[0][0];
         $('td:eq('+index+')', row).html( 'something' );
     }
});
```

Comment: Please don't post [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77449665/10871073) to multiple questions.