# How to get Column Index by Name in dataTables.js?

Tags: datatables

I have a table with a column definition like this:

```
const flagTableCols = [
{                                                   // 0      
  title: "#", 
  name: "LINE_NO",
  className:"text-end"    
},{                                                 // 1
  title: "Check #", 
  name: "CHECK_NM",
  className: "text-center",
},{                                                 // 2
  title: "Proj", 
  name: "PROJECT_NM",
  className: "text-center",
},{                                                 // 3
  title: "Vnd", 
  name: "VENDOR_CD",
  className: "text-center",
},{                                                 // 4
  title: "-", 
  name: "AMOUNT_2", 
  visible: false
}]

let flagTable = $('#flagTable').DataTable({
  data:         flagTableData,
  columns:      flagTableCols,
})
```

I'd like to get the column index by the name of the column, how can I accomplish that?

I've tried playing around with the columns prop like so:

```
flagTable.columns('CHECK_NM')
```

Which seems to give a lot of info, but I can't find the index. I'd like to do something like this:

```
flagTable.columns('CHECK_NM').index   // returns 1
flagTable.columns('VENDOR_CD').index  // returns 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since](https://www.datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) datatables 1.10.0:
You must use :name after column name.

```
var index = table.column('my_column_name:name')[0][0]
var index = table.columns('my_column_name:name')[0][0]
```

[Since](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().names()) datatables 2.0.0:

```
var index = table.columns().names().indexOf( 'my_column_name' );
```

Example v1.x.x:

```
 table = $('#mytable').DataTable( {
     "columns": [
         { "data": "", "name": "my_column_name" }],
     //......... (name can be also set in columnDefs section.

     "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
         var index = table.columns('my_column_name:name')[0][0];
         $('td:eq('+index+')', row).html( 'something' );
     }
});
```